# Parse and capture multiple entries of data in one HTML data table cell

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse data out of an HTML data table. I am successful in using BeautifulSoup to capture the correct data, but it is formatted in a way that cannot be printed cleanly enough to interpret and analyze. As seen in the picture of the table, there are multiple data entries per data cell, with no clear delimiter between the entries. I need all of them but they get printed as one long messy string. Maybe I could use a linebreak as a delimiter?

I tried converting them to a Pandas DataFrame thinking that would neaten up the output but that also failed to produce a clear printout.

I would like to be able to capture and print the first row of the data. Any and all help is appreciated.

The data table: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75iwv.png)

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

path = 'Z:\\folderwithhtmlemail'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'MsoNormalTable'})

rows = table.findAll("tr")[1:2]
        data = {
            'ID' : [],
            'Available Quota' : [],
            'Live Weight Pounds' : [],
            'Price' : [],
            'Date Posted' : []
            }
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.findAll("td")
            data['ID'].append(cols[0].get_text())
            data['Available Quota'].append(cols[1].get_text())
            data['Live Weight Pounds'].append(cols[2].get_text())
            data['Price'].append(cols[3].get_text())
            data['Date Posted'].append(cols[4].get_text())
        fishData = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(fishData)
```

What gets printed without converting to a DataFrame:

```
{'Price': ['$1.45$0.80$0.55$0.50'], 'Live Weight Pounds': ['3,0045723,206538'], 'Available Quota': ['GOM CODGOM HADDDABSGOM YT'], 'Date Posted': ['9/10'], 'ID': ['2119']}
```

What gets printed when converting to a DataFrame:

```
Available Quota Date Posted    ID Live Weight Pounds  \
0  GOM CODGOM HADDDABSGOM YT        9/10  2119   3,0045723,206538   

              Price  
0  $1.45$0.80$0.55$0.50
```

The HTML code:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><b>Subject: </b>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota</td></tr><tr><td><b>From: </b>Claire Fitz-Gerald <claire@capecodfishermen.org></td></tr><tr><td><b>Date: </b>9/10/2014 5:41 PM</td></tr></table><br>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; "><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book";
    panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi";
    panose-1:2 11 7 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
span.EmailStyle18
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Please see below quota listings.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Thanks,<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style='color:#DE3500'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Wednesday, September 10, 2014 11:34 AM<br><b>To:</b> David Leveille<br><b>Subject:</b> NEFS 2 Available Quota<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:#1F487E'>AVAILABLE QUOTA FY 2014</span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'><o:p></o:p></span></p><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="75%" style='width:75.3%'><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>ID <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Available Quota <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Live Weight Pounds <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Price <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Date Posted <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>2119<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>DABS<br>GOM YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>3,004<br>572<br>3,206<br>538<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.45<br>$0.80<br>$0.55<br>$0.50<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>9/10<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1484<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>2,500<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Trade for 2,000 Greysole<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>9/4<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1153<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM YT<br>GOM COD<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5,000<br>800<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.60<br>$1.50<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>8/19<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>512<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GOM COD<br>POLL<br>WHITE HAKE<br>GOM HADD<br>RED<br>GREYSOLE<br>DABS<br>GOM BB<br>GOM YELLOWTail<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>63<br>687<br>16955<br>18278<br>8049<br>1906<br>6436<br>5795<br>4985<br>9279<br>11128<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>PACKAGE <br>$53,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>8/11<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>485<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1009<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>TRADE FOR 400 GOM COD<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>7/25<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>160<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>Pollock<br>GOM HADD<br>REDFISH<br>GREYSOLE<br>DABS<br>GOM BB<br>GOM YELLOWTAIL<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>977<br>91<br>133<br>56<br>176<br>1109<br>1675<br>614<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>PACKAGE <br>$2,700<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>7/14<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>133<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>POLLOCK<br>GOM HADD<br>GOM BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5889<br>432<br>1660<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.01<br>$1.20<br>$0.10<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>7/9<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>001<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GOM HADD<br>GB YELLOWTAIL<br>SNE YELLOWTAIL<br>GB BB<br>GOM BB<br>SNE BB<br>POLLOCK<br>REDFISH<br>DABS<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1235<br>4032<br>949<br>2921<br>4102<br>8880<br>3217<br>175990<br>148106<br>26775<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.10<br>$1.00<br>$1.10<br>$0.40<br>$0.10<br>$0.10<br>$0.35<br>$0.01<br>$0.03<br>$0.47<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>7/2<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1043<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM HADD<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.10<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6/24<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>310B<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>DABS<br>WHAKE<br>POLL<br>RED<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>4154<br>12419<br>3120<br>65234<br>76610<br>2121<br>7285<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.65<br>$0.60<br>$0.20<br>$0.015<br>$0.015<br>$0.45<br>$0.10<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6/24<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>513<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>GOM BB<br>SNE BB<br>WHITE HAKE<br>GREYSOLE<br>DABS<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>323<br>1955<br>243<br>4686<br>1285<br>243<br>2139<br>1134<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.65<br>$1.45<br>$0.80<br>$0.10<br>$0.40<br>$0.20<br>$1.50<br>$0.55<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6/23<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>588<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>GOM BB<br>DABS<br>GOM YT<br>WHAKE<br>POLL<br>REDFISH<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>42<br>462<br>11752<br>960<br>9989<br>2884<br>6172<br>740<br>10314<br>2705<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.00<br>$0.55<br>$1.60<br>$1.15<br>$0.10<br>$0.60<br>$0.60<br>$0.10<br>$0.01<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/29<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1578<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GB BB<br>GOM BB<br>Whake<br>POLL<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1755<br>3965<br>2727<br>9227<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.20<br>$0.15<br>$0.20<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878A<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=223 style='width:167.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM HADD<br>GOM BB<br>GB BB<br>POLL<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=132 style='width:98.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>358<br>7873<br>6762<br>186550<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=201 style='width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.10<br>$0.05<br>$0.05<br>$0.0075<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/12<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=305 style='width:229.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML representation of the table? Seems like it is a nested table and you might need another loop.

Comment: please post html sample code

Comment: I'm sorry for being a beginner with HTML but can you just clarify what exactly you mean by HTML code or HTML representation of the table? I think I know what you guys mean, and I'll post what I think it is, but just correct me if what I post is wrong.

Comment: I added what I think you guys are referring to, but btw I had to delete a chunk of it (the bottom quarter or so) because I am limited to 30,000 characters per SO post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(html, attrs={'class':'MsoNormalTable'})
```